# facebook 3,18 doesnt work in apportable

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-iphone, facebook-ios-sdk, apportable

I am using Facebook sdk 3.18 and apportable indie version sdk.
my facebook is not working.

According to apportable documentation ,they dont support facebook sdk above 3.5.3 but that is very old SDK.

so Is there any way so that this can work?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I already did that but no response from there.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the [Apportable fork of the iOS Facebook SDK](https://github.com/apportable/ApportableFacebookSDK) which works around known issues on Android.

There is also sample code that exercises the ApportableFacebookSDK in the [facebook-sdk branch of Spin](https://github.com/apportable/Spin/tree/facebook-sdk)

Comment: apportable has forked old facebook sdk ,I am trying to use bridge kit and write a code using android native API. Is there any other way to do this other then this?